# MSVC Linker Output Encoding Issue in a UTF-8 Environment

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake, encoding

I am encountering a problem with encoding in the error output from the MSVC linker when building my C++ project on Windows. The error messages from the linker appear as garbled text in my console, which is set to UTF-8 encoding.

My project uses CMake as the build system and is developed in the JetBrains CLion IDE. All of my source files are encoded in UTF-8. My system's locale is also set to UTF-8, and the console is using code page 65001 (UTF-8).

Here is an example of the output:

```
agentprocesscontroller.obj : error LNK2019: ����������ⲿ���� "public: void __cdecl DDS_UserInteractManager::TopicData<class boost::shared_ptr<struct EnvSimuData::vec_EntityBasicData::DataType>,struct DDS_UserInteractManager::in_tag>::publish(class boost::shared_ptr<struct EnvSimuData::vec_EntityBasicData::DataType> const &)" (?publish@?$TopicData@V?$shared_ptr@UDataType@vec_EntityBasicData@EnvSimuData@@@boost@@Uin_tag@DDS_UserInteractManager@@@DDS_UserInteractManager@@QEAAXAEBV?$shared_ptr@UDataType@vec_EntityBasicData@EnvSimuData@@@boost@@@Z)�������ں��� ...
```

I am unsure of how to solve this issue. Is there a way to change the encoding of the MSVC linker's output, or is this a known issue with a different solution? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I have already tried:

1. I have set `/utf-8` compile option in the CMakeLists.txt file for MSVC:

   ```
   if (MSVC)
       set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS /utf-8)
       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS /utf-8)
       # enable boost exception handling
       set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "/EHsc ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}")
   endif ()
   ```
2. I have confirmed that the console's code page is set to 65001 (UTF-8) by using `chcp` command.
3. I have confirmed that all of my source files are encoded in UTF-8.
4. I tested this with a simple program that intentionally causes a linker error, and it will also output in garbled text.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo();  // Function declaration without a definition

int main() {
    foo();  // Call to undefined function
    return 0;
}
```

Interestingly, this issue only occurs with linker errors. Compilation errors display correctly in the console.

Here is an example of a compilation error that displays correctly:

```cpp
F:\Program\SimCSC\ProxyV2\main.cpp(10): error C2146: 语法错误: 缺少“;”(在标识符“QApplication”的前面) [F:\Program\SimCSC\ProxyV2\cmake-build-debug\ProxyV2.vcxproj]
```

Despite all these settings, the MSVC linker's output still appears garbled when there are linking errors.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly: the purpose of this question is to get readable linker messages (and not to solve this particular LNK2019 error)?

Comment: Looking at the linker options, I don't see an option to produce UTF-8 diagnostics. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/linker-options?view=msvc-170

Comment: There used to be a bug in ninja (used under the hood by cmake) causing this. See https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/issues/1195. The cause was that ninja wasn't aware of the output encoding of tools like the linker and incorrectly combined output with different encodings. Can you check that you have a recent ninja version? I don't think that any cmake options, command options or source code encodings will have any effect on the linker messages.

Comment: Are you ok with getting errors in English? I believe setting `VSLANG` env variable to `1033` disables localization.

Comment: @Codo, I apologize for not providing additional information for such a long time. Yeah, I'm just trying to fix the garbled code. Regarding the use of ninja, I switched the generator to Visual Studio in Clion (instead of the default ninja) and still had the garble issue. 
" "